# c# class in a session state?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My senior project is building a reservation system in ASP.NET/C#. Part of my senior project is to have c# classes (and basically use everything ive learned in the past few years). One thing Im trying to do is after I instantiate a new "user" class I need it to travel between the pages. I know session states holds variables, so I figured a session state would work where I can simply type "Session["blah"]." and have access to its members. But I dont see that happening. I realize session states are HTTP context, so i doubted it would work anyway. But  is there any other way in which I can accomplish what I need without instantiating a new user class every time? I know its a webpage...but im also trying to make it as much as a functional online program as I can.

Just for coder's sake, heres the code snippet im working with:

```
    cDatabaseManager cDM = new cDatabaseManager();

    string forDBPass = Encryptdata(pass_txt.Text.ToString());
    string fullName = fname_txt.Text.ToString() + " " + lname_txt.Text.ToString();

    cDM.regStudent(email_txt.Text.ToString(), forDBPass, fullName, num_txt.Text.ToString(), carrier_ddl.SelectedValue.ToString(), this);

    //ADD - getting a cStudent
    cUser studentUser = new cStudent(fullName, forDBPass, email_txt.Text.ToString());

    //ADD - session states
    Session["cStudent"] = studentUser;

    //Session["cStudent"].      //session state will not work with what I am doing
    //ADD - transfer to campus diagram
```

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

I want to thank all of you who posted and commented! Ive learned alot from this short discussion. All your answers helped me understand!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? This should work just fine. Do you get an exception? Aren't you able to retreive the object from the session?

Comment: Please consider following the C# (and .NET) naming guidelines when writing code in C#. People who have to maintain your code later will thank you.

Comment: The issue is when I type "Session["cStudent"]." I dont have access to my functions. Example: `Session["cStudent"].getName()` does not give my functionality. The four functions I get with intellesense is: equals, gethashcode, gettype, and tostring.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Where might I find these guidelines? This is a senior project and I doubt anyone will be supporting my code when I graduate (even if it is implemented). Thank you for your comment though, it is truly appreciated and I would like to see/use them.

Comment: @KevinFauver - [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are Microsoft's standards.  Some places have their own standards, and adapting is part of working as a developer, but by default you should try to follow Microsoft.

Comment: @KevinFauver - It's good to get into the habit of using the recommended naming guideline. You won't be programming solo forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment:

> The issue is when I type `"Session["cStudent"]."` I don't have access to my functions. Example: `Session["cStudent"].getName()` does not give my functionality.

This is because the `[]` indexer for `Session` sets/returns `object`s.  The compiler does not know that you stored a `cUser` object and so you can't access the properties directly without a cast:

```
string name = ((cUser)Session["cStudent"]).getName();
```

There are two things that could go wrong here:

1. If `Session["cStudent"]` is `null` you will get a `NullReferenceException`
2. If `Session["cStudent"]` is not really a `cUser` you will get an `InvalidCastException`

You should check these conditions and react appropriately if one of them is true.

Also, as others have pointed out, the `cUser` class needs to be marked as `Serializable` in order to be stored in `Session` state.

Comment: last question on this particular subject, since cStudent inherits from cUser, if I serialize cUser will cStudent also be serialized?

Comment: `If Session["cStudent"] is not really a cUser you will get an InvalidCastException` its things like this, I sometimes wonder why `Session` is not templatized

Comment: @KevinFauver No, you have to include Serializable on child classes as well.

Comment: @Aniket Because you can't have a generic index operator, so it would have to be a get/set function like `T GetSession<T>(string key)` and `void SetSession<T>(string key, T value)`  Also since you have to specify the type anyways it doesn't buy you much over a cast.

Answer (score 4):

Session stores item as objects. As long as your class inherits from Object (which it does) you can store it there. Quick caveat, it stores that object using Serialization, so your class must be serializable.

Add a property to your class like so:

```
public cStudent CurrentStudent
{
    get {
        if(Session["CurrentUser"] == null)
            return null;

        return (cStudent)Session["CurrentUser"];
    }
    set {
        Session["CurrentUser"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `set(cStudent value)` - what language is that? Certainly not c#

Comment: @zespri - I think VB.net allows parameters to setters, although you wouldn't structure it that way.

Comment: @zespri: Oops :$. Fixed. Nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

When retrieving an object value from session state cast it to appropriate type.

```
[Serializable]    
public class student
    {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

In Page1:

```
student s1 = new student();
s1.FirstName ="James";
s1.LastName = "Bond";
Session["blah"] = s1;
```

And when you want to access Session["blah"] in page 2

```
student s2 = (Session["blah"] !=null ? (student)Session["blah"] : null);
```

Now you can access properties of s2 as s2.FirstName, s2.LastName

Comment: the student class needs to have the [Serializable] attribute.

Comment: If the session value is null, this line will throw an error: `s2 = (student)Session["blah"];`. Also, why set s2 to a news student instance? All you are doing is adding another instance on the heap when you repoint that variable to the session instance.